# Metric induced on linear group orbit is Riemannian homogeneous

Tags: representation-theory, riemannian-geometry, lie-groups, smooth-manifolds, isometry

Consider the standard representation of $ SO_3(\mathbb{R}) $ acting on $ \mathbb{R}^3 $. Then for any nonzero vector $ v \in \mathbb{R}^3 $ the orbit
$$
\mathcal{O}_v=\{gv: g \in  SO_3(\mathbb{R}) \}
$$
is a sphere of radius $ |v| $. And the metric on the sphere, induced by the Euclidean metric on the ambient space $ \mathbb{R}^3 $, is the round metric. A round sphere is Riemannian homogeneous (in other words, the isometry group acts transitively).

This leads to my question. Let $ G $ be a compact group and $ \pi:G \to GL_n(\mathbb{R}) $ a representation. For any $ v \in \mathbb{R}^n $ define the orbit of $ v $ to be
$$
\mathcal{O}_v=\{\pi(g)v: g \in  G \}
$$
Let $ g $ be the metric on $ \mathcal{O}_v $ induced by the Euclidean metric on $ \mathbb{R}^n $. Then is $ (\mathcal{O}_v,g) $ Riemannian homogeneous? In other words, does the isometry group $ Iso(\mathcal{O}_v,g) $ act transitively on $ \mathcal{O}_v $?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is false. As a counterexample, consider an $SO(3)$ action on $\mathbb{R}^n$ conjugate to the standard one by a non-orthogonal invertible matrix $A$. The orbits are non-spherical ellipsoids, which are not homogeneous.

The statement is true specifically of *orthogonal* representations, and of course every representation of a compact group is orthogonal with respect to *some* inner product, but not necessarily the standard one.

Comment: I see. If we stick to the standard inner product on $\mathbb{R}^n $ but specialize to the case of an orthogonal representation $ \pi: G \to O_n(\mathbb{R}) $ then is there a simple proof of the fact that linear group orbits are homogeneous with respect to the induced metric? Is the proof basically that the induced metric is $ \pi(G) $ invariant?

Comment: @IanGershonTeixeira One way is to use the fact that for an orbit $S$, the $G$-action $\theta$ on $S$ is pretty much defined by the requirement that the inclusion $\iota:S\to\mathbb{R}^n$ be $G$-equivariant. Thus, for $g\in G$ we have$$\theta_g^*(\iota^*\delta)=(\iota\circ\theta_g)^*\delta=(\pi_g\circ\iota)^*\delta=\iota^*(\pi_g^*\delta)=\iota^*\delta$$where $\delta$ is the Euclidean metric on $\mathbb{R}^n$.